# SlideDown() doesn't work with After() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, slidedown

I want to add an element to a list and I want that it slide down when is added. But using `after()` method it doesnt work. Why?

**Html** code:

```
<ul id="myUL">
 <li> First Item <li>
 <li> Second Item <li>
 <li> Third Item <li>
 <li> Fourth Item <li>
```

Add

**Js** code:

```
$('#add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();     
  $('li:last').after('<li> A New Item </li>').slideDown("slow");
});
```

**Fiddle** full code: http://jsfiddle.net/gxs46L0u/

Comment: close your elements first `</li>` and `</ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to close those `li` tags. HTML:

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <li> First Item </li>
  <li> Second Item </li>
  <li> Third Item </li>
  <li> Fourth Item </li>
</ul>
```

Then for the js here's a quick and dirty way to do it:

```
$('#add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();     
  $('li:last').after('<li style="display:none"> A New Item </li>');
  $('li:last').slideDown("slow");
});
```

You add an element without showing it and in the next step the slideDown will make it appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw9yLdt7/

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <li> First Item </li>
   <li> Second Item </li>
   <li> Third Item </li>
   <li> Fourth Item </li>
</ul>
<a id="add" href="#">Add</a>
```

USe this jquery:

```
$('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    $('<li> A New Item </li>').appendTo('#myUL').hide().slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/gxs46L0u/4/)

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <li> First Item </li>
  <li> Second Item </li>
  <li> Third Item </li>
  <li> Fourth Item </li>
</ul>
<a id="add" href="#">Add</a>

$('#add').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myUL').append('<li> A New Item </li>');
});
```

Problem is your HTML is not closed properly close them and use append